# Autocomplete form with data from json array

Tags: php, json

I have a booking event script that works perfectly fine. I had to make a change to pass the client_id to get added to the appointment. This is where I'm stuck. I had the first & last names working without an array, but noticed that wasn't a good approach so I added an array.

**fetch.php**

```
    $clientarray = array();
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        $clientarray[] = $row;
    }


echo json_encode($clientarray);
```

The above outputs: [{"id":"57","first_name":"JEFFERSON","last_name":"ANDREAS"}];

**index.php**

```
    $(document).ready(function(e)
    {
        $("#title").keyup(function()
        {
            $("#here").show();
            var x = $(this).val();
            $.ajax(
                {
                    type:'GET',
                    url:'fetch.php',
                    data: 'q='+x, /// start search only when first character is entered. q not empty.
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        $("#here").html(data); /// display results in <div id=here>
                    }
                    ,
                });
        });
    });
```

The script above displays the search results in a  where I want to click on a result and autocomplete 3 input boxes: client_id, first_name, last_name.

Comment: Question is unclear

Comment: So in the div "here", can you read the JSON string? What is your question? You want to know how compile three input when the div here is clicked? I can't understand your question

Comment: Yes. The div "here" shows the results from fetch.php as a list of matches. First I need a clean list eg (John Smith) with a hidden client id nothing else. When clicked autocomplete 3 input text boxes (client_id, first_name, last_name) so that I can submit my form and save to the mysql db as a booking event with the time that I already have working.